# How can I force the Market to reinstall an installed app?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I have an app, installed from the Market, which I just updated. The "updating" notification was present for several hours, so it appears to have gotten stuck somehow.

I believe it now claims to be the current version, but to be sure, **is it possible to tell the Market to re-download and reinstall the current version of the app?**

Comment: Did you try a reboot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to tell the Market to reinstall an app.  I was hoping you could do it through the Market website but I just tried and it refused to install an already-installed app.  (Which bothers me because my phone and the website will *definitely* be out of sync regularly, I do too many third-party restores and so on.)

That said, you could clear the data for the Market (Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> All -> Market -> Force Close, Clear Data) and reboot your phone, then start up the Market again and look to see whether the update is available again or not.  If it's not then you can trust that the latest version is installed since it grabbed that info directly from the system, and if not you can attempt the update again.

Comment: +1.  Clearing the Market data and cache is a sure way to get back in sync.  In later Android versions (2.2+) you may also have to clear the data for "Google Services Framework" app.  Upon first launch after making you accept the terms of service, the Market always rebuilds the list of currently installed apps and their versions.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to have been successful, though the exercise found a couple of other apps that needed updates.

Comment: This is no longer relevant in modern Android versions; there's no "Market" app.

Answer (score 6):

You can't "reinstall". All you can do is just simply uninstall it and install again.

Answer (score 0):

I take the back up of all the applications regularly to my SD Card. Sometimes I uninstall them because of some issues. If I need them I install from my SD Card directly.

Now I open the My Market Account in Android Website using my Google account. It shows all the installed applications even though I removed them and installed again.

I feel this answer isn't completely relevant to the question. But I am sharing a way to reinstall the applications from Android Market. Anyways you can remove the application and install it again.